# How to get current Users Email ID in GMAIL ADDONS

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api, gmail-addons

I am learning to make gmail addons.
But I am stuck at a point on how to access email address value of user who using addons.

After Reading I get that I will need this permission
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email

But how to actually get email address when user opens addon in Gmail

Please can anybody help me on this

Comment: What do you need the id for? You can just use the string "me" if it's for other Apps. Otherwise, I'm not sure if you can simply get it, but I guess you can fetch it from the user's gmail threads for example.

Comment: I am using email id to check whether this user registered with our system or not - so i am going to make a api call to my servers that  is why  - hey could you please provide example --

Comment: `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()` You'll need AUTH.FULL for every user for this to probably work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
var emailAddress = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
```

Comment: Thanks Glen - Can you give me link from where I read more about this function and others - and know about how can I access various properties.

Comment: @SandeepChikhale, you can find this one here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getEffectiveUser()  The more obvious `getActiveUser` does not seem to work in Gmail Add-ons.

Comment: In working with my add-on, something changed, and now `getActiveUser()` works, and `getEffectiveuser()` fails saying "You do not have permission to call getEffectiveUser"!

Comment: And adding  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"  back into the manifest file (appsscript.json) got them both working again.

Comment: Even with "googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email", `getActiveUser()` does not work for me, only `getEffectiveUser()` works. Btw, I have to use `USER_ACCESSING` in the field of `executeAs` in the manifest file.